# Click button programatically in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs, react-router

In my react-native app I have a screen where it contains a form.
I wanna submit the form on loading the screen because the values in form is gonna be constant.
So i wanna submit the form on loading.
Is it possible?
Can someone help me..

```
<PrimaryButton
          // onPress={onSubmit(siteUrl)}
          onPress={() => onSubmit(siteUrl)}
          text={translate("general.enter")}
          style={styles.buttonEnter}
          mode={isSiteUrlSubmitted ? "loading" : undefined}
        />
```

i tried this
**onPress={onSubmit(siteUrl)}**
but it shows **Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

Comment: can you show what is happening inside onSubmit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `onSubmit()` in `React.useEffect`

as such

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   onSubmit() 
}, []);
```

When you add blank parentheses
It will only be performed once in loading

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
I hope this is what you mean
```useEffect(() => {
    onSubmit(siteUrl);
  });```
But i got a error **Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

Comment: hi @sreenumalae  add ``,[]`` after } in ``useEffect``
as ``useEffect(() => {     onSubmit(siteUrl);   },[]);``

Comment: Hii @yoel I did as you said but still i got the same error 
**Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

Comment: @sreenumalae  Did you remove it from ``onPress``?

Comment: Yes I tried by removing and i also tried by removing the whole PrimaryButton.

Comment: @sreenumalae Wait, does onSubmit cause the page to run again?
If so it is never possible
It's an endless loop

Comment: not onSubmit but the same page run for twice before rendering the form